# Не получается реализовать таймер

Tags: javascript, html5

```
function timer(){
   var time = getvalue();
   var time_query = Math.round(time/60000);
   var min = time_query;
   var sec = document.getElementById('sec').innerHTML;

   if(sec > 0) sec--;
   else{
    sec = 3;
   if(min > 0) min--;
   }
   /*if*/
   document.getElementById('min').innerHTML = min;
   document.getElementById('sec').innerHTML = sec;  
}
```

Привет всем! Такая проблема, хочу реализовать таймер. Но после "time_query" 
значение не изменяется. Что можно сделать? Прога [тут](https://codepen.io/SeQwerMan/pen/jBMaRK)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function getTimer() {
  var counter = 0;
  return function() {
    counter++;
    console.log(counter);
  };
}

setInterval(getTimer(), 500);
```